# In Reporting Services 2008 is there a replacement for Me.Value?

Tags: reporting-services

In some of our SQL Server Reporting Services reports we wrote for SQL 2005, we used the Me.Value in the hidden expression to determine if the cell should be shown. This worked fine with SSRS 2005 (even though it probably shouldn't have).

However, it no longer works with SSRS 2008. Is there an alternative (other than using the actual field) that we can use?

**Edit:** I need something that works in both SSRS 2005 & 2008 as these reports will be distributed to multiple places.

Comment: Define "no longer works". Do you get an error? Does it silently continue but acts as if the textbox's value was empty? or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the Control?

Something like:

```
ReportItems!TextBox1.Value
```

[ReportItems on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934329.aspx)

Comment: Cool, although I can't just copy and paste the expression to all my controls that need it, it still allows me to change the expression for the value of the textbox without changing the visible expression.